# MS SQL Constraint on a column

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I have a table called Products this is how it looks like and I am trying to create a constraint on [IsDefaultProductKey] column, that any time a value is added to it, it needs be an active product key.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [ProductId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
     [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsDefaultProductKey] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_products_IsActive]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [IsActive]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_Product_IsDefaultProductKey] FOREIGN KEY([IsDefaultProductKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([ProductId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_Product_IsDefaultProductKey]
GO
```

If these are the entries in the table, row 4 should not be allowed to have a value of 1, since 1 is inactive. How can I go about adding a constraint on the table for that

```
ProductId   Name    IsActive    IsDefaultProductKey
1            Test1  0             NULL
2            Test2  1             NULL
3            Test3  0                2
4            Test4   0             1 (Should not let me do this)
```

Based on suggestion, I created this UDF. But still not acting 100% the way I want it.. Please suggest.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products]( [ProductId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
[Name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL, 
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL, 
[IsDefaultProductKey] [int] NULL, 
) 
go

Create FUNCTION dbo.CheckProduct (@IsDefaultProductKey int)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @retval int
    SELECT @retval = 0
    Select @retval = 1
    FROM [Products]
    WHERE ProductId = @IsDefaultProductKey and IsActive = 1 
  RETURN @retval
END;
GO
--Select CheckProduct(1)

ALTER TABLE [Products] 
  ADD CONSTRAINT chkActiveProduct 
  CHECK (IsDefaultProductKey = null or dbo.CheckProduct(IsDefaultProductKey) = 1); 
go
```

Comment: and what would happen when you want to deactivate a column? Your trigger would first have to change the IsDefaultProductKey which seems cumbersome. This looks like you are trying to smash a FK into the base table instead of adding another table to keep up with this parent/child relationship. Can you elaborate on what the end goal is?

Comment: Thanks @scsimon, so basically yes it will need to be going both ways. ProductId 4 cant have 1 as a IsDefaultProductKey cause its currently inactive. And No one should be able to make ProductKey2 as Inactive because its currently in use by productId 3.

Comment: End goal is a check that if IsDefaultProductKey is used, it needs to be on an active ProductId. IsDefaultProductKey can stay null otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CHECK CONSTRAINT that calls a UDF that queries the table to see if the ProductId referenced by `IsDefaultProductKey` is Active or not.

EDIT:
Since you need the constraint to check both ways, you would create a UDF that has parameters for `ProductId`, `IsActive` and `IsDefaultProductKey`.

Inside the function, if there is a non-NULL value for `IsDefaultProductKey`, then you need to query the table to see if the row with that `ProductId` is Active.   If not, then the function needs to return `false`.

ALSO, if the `IsActive` parameter is passed a value of 0, then you need to check the table to make sure that no row has a `IsDefaultProductKey` equal to the value of the `ProductId` parameter.   If there is such a row, then the function needs to return `false`.

But if neither of those cases occur, the function returns `true`, and in the CHECK CONSTRAINT, you then just test to see if the function returns `true`.

Comment: Can you give me a code example please. I am not sure how to call a UDF from a check constraint and use its return value.  Thanks much for your help with this.

Comment: This is what I have so far, please suggest. I have the code, how can I put it for input. This comment section is too small.

Comment: @Sarah Adding your code as an answer, as you did, is fine.   If you have further questions about it, you should either edit your question so you can add code there, or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your questions completely. However looks like you want to apply a check constraint based on the value of other column. The issue which I see in your SQL is you are applying a column level constraint, while I think you need to apply a table level constraint. Please see below sample based on my understanding of your question.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [ProductId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsDefaultProductKey] [int] NULL,
         CONSTRAINT ck_contraint CHECK
         (
             (IsActive = 1 AND (IsDefaultProductKey>0) ) 

         )
   )
```

Comment: I am not sure that is going to work as the OP wants, it is going to be using the IsActive field in the row being inserted\updated not the default product row.  I think you'll need a trigger to do this.

Comment: Thanks @PhilS, appreciate your help with this. I really dont want to use a trigger as it should be a simple check on IsdefaultProductKey.. If someone puts a value on IsDefaultProductKey it needs a check on that if that productId is active or not, if it is active.. Good.. If not.. Don't let the user update that row.

Comment: @Sarah: Did you try my scripts?

Comment: Just trying that as we speak.. So first thing noticed, that it wouldnt let me add a row like this  Test2 False..  I should be able to have as many inactive products as I want. Only constraint should come when I am adding a IsdefaultProductKey. It needs a check at that time.

Comment: You can add one more condition in that - CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [ProductId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
     [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsDefaultProductKey] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ck_contraint CHECK
  (
    (IsActive = 1 AND (IsDefaultProductKey>0) ) 
    or (IsDefaultProductKey is NULL)
   
)
    )

Comment: @Gaurav ,thanks checking now.. nope wouldnt allow me to have a productKey for IsDefaultProductKey when inactive flag is False.

Comment: Can you please send me your insert statement?

Comment: @Gaurav I am pretty sure you have not understood the question correctly.   Your answer is pretty much what I started to type, until I re-read the question.  Your answer only looks at each row individually.   The actual question is how to look at a different row based on the `ProductId` referenced in `IsDefaultProductKey`.   Look closely at the desired results in the original question.   The only way a CHECK CONSTRAINT can look at other rows in the same table is with a UDF.

Comment: Ah! I got it now . @TabAlleman - Thanks for clarification. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a trigger not a constraint to do this.  Something like:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER DefaultNotActive ON [dbo].[Products]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM [dbo].[Products] p 
           JOIN inserted AS i 
           ON p.[ProductId] = i.[IsDefaultProductKey] 
           WHERE p.[IsActive] = 0
          )
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Default Product is inactive.', 16, 1);
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN 
END;
```

It might need to be more complex if you also need the default product key to exist.  Currently this will allow inserts\updates where the default product key is an id that does not have an existing row in the table

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tab Allemnan, Here is the solution I found. Works both ways.

```
Create FUNCTION CheckProduct (@IsDefaultProductKey int, @ProductId int, @IsActive bit)
RETURNS bit
AS 
BEGIN
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ret bit;
    if (@IsDefaultProductKey is not NULL)
    begin  
        SELECT @ret = 1  
        FROM [Products] p   
        WHERE p.ProductID = @IsDefaultProductKey   
            AND p.IsActive = 1; 
    end
    else   -- If @IsDefaultProductKey is null
         Select @ret = 1

    If (@IsActive = 0)  -- If Product is made inactive, make sure that its not a defaultkey for any product. 
    Begin
         SELECT @ret = 0  
        FROM [Products] p   
        WHERE p.IsDefaultProductKey = @ProductId   
    End


     IF (@ret IS NULL)   
        SET @ret = 0;  
    RETURN @ret;  
END; 
END;
--Select dbo.CheckProduct (2,1,0)
GO
ALTER TABLE [Products] 
  ADD CONSTRAINT chkActiveProduct 
  CHECK (dbo.CheckProduct(IsDefaultProductKey,ProductId, IsActive)=1); 
go
```